# can't access servlet, 404 not found

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

edit 10/8/10 @ 8:20am est - since I can't make this work in prod, I'll try to make it fail in test.

edit 10/8/10 @ 4:30pm est - having a great time!!! NOT.  Ok, hell continues.  I learned earlier today that we're also running Apache httpd as a separate process.  So we're thinking maybe we're not forwarding the request to Tomcat somehow.  I am not running httpd in my test environment.

Edit 10/8/10 @ 8:20pm - found out that the server also had httpd running on it.  httpd was only forwarding jsp requests to Tomcat.  Apache was eating the servlet requests, trying to serve static pages (?) and failing of course.  I hacked the bajezus out of worker2.properties to make httpd forward the requests.  Ouch.

---

Tomcat 5.5, RedHat linux.

I created a servlet which of course runs fine in our test environment.  I moved it to production and I fail with a 404 error. According to the catalina log the servlet seems to load properly.

I'm at wits end - I don't know how to troubleshoot this.  It's almost like I have misspelled the servlet name somewhere.

Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Pdf Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pdf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.thop.exp.PdfServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pdf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

I am browsing to `www.myurl.net/PdfServlet/pdf`.  I believe I have this rooted correctly. and the name of the war file is PdfServlet.war.

Any ideas on a problem, or ideas on what I can do to get an idea?

---

Here's the log.

```
INFO: Installing web application at context path /PdfServlet from URL file:/mnt/san00/aaadata_root/ROOT/PdfServlet
Oct 7, 2010 11:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
INFO: XML validation disabled
Oct 7, 2010 11:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationConfig
INFO: Missing application web.xml, using defaults only StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[aaa.net].StandardContext[]
Oct 7, 2010 11:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost getDeployer
INFO: Create Host deployer for direct deployment ( non-jmx )
Oct 7, 2010 11:32:50 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 7, 2010 11:32:50 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK2: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Oct 7, 2010 11:32:50 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/25  config=/usr/share/tomcat5/conf/jk2.properties
Oct 7, 2010 11:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4325 ms
```

Comment: if you remove the /pdf are you able to hit your index.jsp file? This should give you an indication if your app is loaded while removing your servlet and mapping out of the equation

Comment: Interesting.  Yes I can.

Comment: Is there anything in the log?

Comment: Out of the box, tomcat give you two log files in the same directory, catalina.log and localhost.log. Assuming you haven't changed this, do you see any errors in those files? I know you already checked catalina

Comment: Original post amended with catalina.out.  Note the 'Missing application web.xml'...

Comment: It appears localhost.log has been turned off.  There's just an old directory full of localhost files from 2004 :-/

Comment: I just made a webapp with your web.xml file and there were no problems. Check the structure of your war file and make sure it is ok. WEB-INF folder contains web.xml file and classes folder. classes contains  com/thop/exp/PdfServlet.class

Comment: Does your Servlet Forward to any other resources?

Comment: @sean The servlet picks a PDF off a remote server and streams it to the invoking webpage.

Comment: @sean the WEB-INF has lib/, classes/, web.xml, and sun_web.xml_aaa - I renamed the latter.  lib has a troublesome log4j jar I renamed to log4j.jar_aaa  The PdfServlet.class file looks like it's in the right place.

Comment: If you don't already have it setup already, I would recommend adding Log4j, or some other logging into your servlet and try and see what it is doing step by step. It could be that the servlet cant reach the remote server (firewall or some other reason) so the response is getting lost in a 404. It appears based on everything I have seen so far that this should be working.

Comment: I was getting some ghastly errors when I had log4j in the lib folder.  I had some debugging logic in the code which I removed so I would have no log4j dependency.

Comment: What does the bit in the log about the missing web.xml mean?

Comment: Not 100% sure on the exception. Googling around, Most people indicate this happens when they redeploy, or copy a war file over an existing one. upon restart, Tomcat is trying to delete the old unpacked application. If it fails to clean up the directory properly then the next restart fails to deploy the application properly. here is one reference: http://www.junlu.com/msg/147100.html

Comment: Do you have a web server such as apache httpd in front of tomcat on your production server? If so are there any url rewrite or forwarding rules configured?

Comment: @Tony Ennis: I've replicated a similar problem on tomcat 6. I've taken a perfectly working webapp and dropped it into ROOT. It shows me the index page but 404s on all servlets - but my JSPs can work. Can you try (1) a JSP in the webapp (2) put the webapp outside of ROOT

Comment: You shouldn't be putting web apps into ROOT.  I'd recommend packaging them as WAR files and putting them into /webapps.

Comment: @duffymo I agree.  I inherited this 9 days ago :-/ They've made a directory for each virtual host, and then put a ROOT dir under each of those.

Comment: @Tony Ennis: man, that's a good one. Pointer for me next time to ask if Apache fronts Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying to package your web app as a WAR file - name it PDFServlet.war.

Put that into your Tomcat /webapps directory.

The URL in question would be `http://www.myurl.net:8080/PdfServlet/pdf`.

I'm assuming that you've got Tomcat listening on port 8080; if not, add your own port number.

Is there no way to specify which PDF the user wants?  Or is it always the same PDF?

Comment: The PDF names are constructed based upon customer ID and the date.  The servlet fetches the appropriate PDF from a server and streams it to the jsp.

Comment: So customer comes in via credentials?  Or is it a REST query (e.g., ?custId=X)

Comment: How can I prove that the web.xml above is the one being used?  One of my guys hypothesizes that the servlet isn't being recognized because Tomcat isn't using our web.xml.

Comment: I suppose I haven't thought of it too much, but we have the conf/web.xml under Tomcat with all the MIME mappings and so forth, and the spartan web.xml that's in my servlet.  Does Tomcat slam them together?

Comment: You ought to have a /WEB-INF/web.xml in your project.  I never touch the server configuration.

Comment: Thank goodness.  I just found this.    <!-- This document defines default values for *all* web applications      -->
  <!-- loaded into this instance of Tomcat.  As each application is         -->
  <!-- deployed, this file is processed, followed by the                    -->
  <!-- "/WEB-INF/web.xml" deployment descriptor from your own               -->
  <!-- applications.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 5.5 is a [servlet 2.4 container](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), and you have specified you have a 2.5 web.xml.

If the Tomcat version in test is newer than 5.5 (6 or 7) then try lowering web.xml to 2.4.

---

EDIT:  Ok, then try removing /pdf from web.xml again and see if you can invoke the `com.thop.exp.PdfServlet` class from your index.jsp file.

Comment: Changes made, tomcat restarted, no change in behavior.

Comment: This is the only servlet on the system as far as I know.  Do servlets have to be 'enabled' in a config somewhere?

Comment: I was able to _refer_ to the com.thop.exp.PdfServer class.  I tried to invoke it using a form and got the same error, "Not Found,
The requested URL /PdfServlet/pdf was not found on this server."

Comment: You can do `<%= new com.thop.exp.PdfServer %>` and have its toString output on the JSP page?